# python: comparing strings in a different order

Tags: python, string, sympy

I am doing a maths quiz for my coursework based around differentiation and integration using python 3. I'm finding it difficult to check if the answer, typed in by the user, is correct. 
I'm currently using the code below. However, if the user types in answer but in a different order it is treated as incorrect. for example if the answer was x^5 + 6 but I typed in 6 + x^5 it would be treated as incorrect despite both answers being correct. How would I overcome this issue while keeping the answer in a string state?

```
if self.Answer.text() == FDiffAnswer[1]:
    self.score = self.score + 1
else:
    self.score = self.score + 0
```

Comment: what about x^(5)+6 .. ?

Comment: And what about `x*x*x*x*x+6`, or `1*x^5+6`, etc?

Comment: Perhaps there is a **way** easier approach but if I were you, I would lean towards replacing variables with values and comparing values of answers against the correct one. The number of different ways you can write the correct answer in math is pretty incredible, however there's only one correct value.

Comment: they'll both treated as incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sympy this can be done as follows...

```
x = symbols('x')
// user_input and original_eq are strings
expr1 = sympify(user_input) // user input
expr2 = sympify(original_eq) // Answer
print expr1==expr2
```

> Double equals signs (==) are used to test equality. However, this
>   tests expressions exactly, not symbolically

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs

But this returns True for all the following cases:

```
x**6 + 1 == x**(6) +  1
x**6 + 1 == 1 + x**6
x**3 + 1 == x*x*x +  1
```

PS: Sympy(and Python) uses the symbol `^` for XOR operation. So if you want it to be used as power operation you need to replace it by ** before calling `sympify`

Comment: would this work is the equation has a coefficient but isn't multiplying the unknown. for example, would  5x ** 5 + 1 = 1 + 5*x ** 5

Comment: @mcsethantwi Nope... that is the problem here with sympy... you need to give expressions such that sympy understands ... but still there is a tweak by first parsing the string and if we find some thing like 5x replacing it with 5*x and then calling the sympify function

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval()` the input string with a few different variables and check that the output is correct:

```
user_str = 'x**5 + 6'

x = 4

print('Good Job') if eval(user_str) == 1030 else 'Wrong Answer'
```

Then you can change the value of `x` a few times and continue to check with an expected output to verify that the user's answer evaluates correctly.

Otherwise you can use `split()` and check the output's list for the correct components:

```
user_str = 'x^5+6'

l = user_str.split('+')

if 'x^5' in l and '6' in l and len(l) == 2:
    print('Good Job')
else:
    print('Wrong Answer')
```

Of course using this second method you will need to edit the `split()` parameters and the validation of the `if()` statement, but you should be able to reach your desired check.  You may also want to check the `len()` of the output list to verify that there are no additional components to the answer.